# iTunes 12 doesn't show the correct number of photos to be synced and doesn't sync all photos

Tags: itunes, macos, photos, photos.app

I have iTunes 12.2 on a mac book pro with Yosemite, I use Photos app now instead of iPhotos after importing all of its events into iPhoto, plus I recently added around a few thousand pics and videos to the Photos app, the All Photos option in Photos app shows 4372 photos, whereas in iTunes when I select "copy photos from Photos" and "All photos and albums" options under the "Photos" tab it shows 3858 photos as the total number to be synced, where the hell those 500 photos have gone ?

I searched for a solution but couldn't find any, I also checked out this question: [Why is iTunes only syncing some of the pictures (seemingly randomly) in each Aperture Event to my iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25548/why-is-itunes-only-syncing-some-of-the-pictures-seemingly-randomly-in-each-ape) but couldn't also help me ..

any help would be highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the 4,372 photos are *all of your photos*, as opposed to just *photos to be synced*. In other words, around 500 photos of those photos have already been synced to your iPad.

Comment: I have an iPhone 6 plus, and yes you say right, I have 450 photos already synced in my iPhone, if you calculate it again: 4372-450 = 3922  but iTunes says  there are 3858 photos to be synced, but after the calculation above i have 3922, how come this ?

Comment: @JAHelia You may have deleted them from your iPhone or Photos.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason, I should check: **Include Videos** option before I sync, once checked the total number is updated to the correct one.